# Can I attach multiple click events to an element using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following in a plug-in script:

```
$("#menu")
.on('click','a[href^="/Test"]',function(event){

        event.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        alert(this);
        // Load content
        $('#content').load(href, '', function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            $(this).applyTemplateSetup().buildTableOfContent();
        });
        window.location.hash = '#' + href;

        // Get nav link
        var a = $('#menu a[href="' + href + '"]');
        if (a.length > 0) {
            // Mark as current
            $('#menu a').removeClass('current');
            a.addClass('current');

            // Update breadcrumb
            var breadcrumb = $('#breadcrumb').empty();
            while (a.length > 0) {
                if (a.get(0).nodeName.toUpperCase() == 'A') {
                    var target = a;
                }
                else {
                    var target = a.parent().find('a:first');
                }
                breadcrumb.prepend('<li><a href="' + target.attr('href') + '">' +
                a.contents().filter(function () {
                    return this.nodeType == 3;
                }).first().text()
                + '</a></li>');

                // Check if opened
                var li = a.parent();
                if (li.hasClass('closed')) {
                    li.removeClass('closed');
                }

                a = li.parent().parent().children('a, span');
            }
        }
    });
```

I would like to also set the value of a link when the user clicks. I added this 
on my page but it seems like it does not get called. Is there a problem when
I attach two of the same type of events to an element?

```
$("#menu")
            .on('click', 'a[href^="/Test"]', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var href = $(this).attr('href');
                var pk = href.substr(7, 4);
                var rk = href.substr(12, 4);
                var link = "/Admin/Testss/Edit?pk=" + pk + "&rk=" + rk;
                $('#editLink').data('href', link);
            });
```

Comment: The rest of the first function is relevant, specifically if it is `return false`...

Comment: I added the rest of the function. There's no return false. I am wondering if it's okay to have two event.preventDefault();

Comment: Why do you need 2 click events? It's the same elements youre attaching them to, so just put your code together and make it one event

Comment: @Tom I've had to use multiple click events before - eg when building complex forms which may or may not have some elements present. Each element that depends on a click can register/unregister its own handler as required - Far easier to maintain and more OO

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help so far. I will try to look into what may be wrong now everyone told me it should work okay.

Comment: Do you somehow modify the content of #menu in the first event handler? Maybe in buildTableOfContent()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should work. Make sure that the code which defines the 2nd handler is actually being executed.

Alternatively, you could always modify the first handler you attach to call your (multiple) other functions.

Personally I'd prefer to get the former working as it allows you to attach/detach handlers independantly.

Do you have the same problem if you use [Bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) ?

As mentioned in comments on the Q, if any of the functions returns a `false`, it will prevent the event bubbling.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep it in the one click event, having it in two is redudant